# Erlang parse placeholder variables

Tags: erlang

I am attempting to create a special templating format which must locate occurrences of `{{{--example_id--}}}` and replace that content individually, and get it by the bracket-enclosed value.

My initial attempt was to split my way through and I'm posting some example code below which has – not – been optimized for multiple placeholders yet and can only handle one placeholder at a time.

```
parse_text() ->
    Text = <<"this is text {{{--test_placeholder_1--}}} and this also">>,
    % would not work here:
    % Text = <<"this is text {{{--test_placeholder_1--}}} and this {{{--test_placeholder_2--}}} also">>,
    [_,Tail] = binary:split(Text, [<<"{{{--">>],[global]),
    [Id|_] = binary:split(Tail, [<<"--}}}">>],[global]),

    Pattern = <<"{{{--", Id/binary, "--}}}">>,
    Replacement = get_content(Id),
    Result = binary:replace(Text, Pattern, Replacement),

    io:fwrite("~p\n", [Result]).


get_content(<<"test_placeholder_1">>)->
    <<"test id 1!">>;
get_content(<<"test_placeholder_2">>)->
    <<"test id 2!">>;
get_content(_)->
    <<"not found text!">>.
```

My question is, should I optimize this further to support multiple placeholders in one text, or is there an entirely better approach to handle problems like these?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this is better idea but it works for multiple placeholders

```
parse_text(Input) ->
    List = lists:foldr(
        fun(E, Acc) ->
            case get_content(E) of
                <<"not found text!">> -> [E| Acc];
                Match -> [Match | Acc]
            end 
        end, [], binary:split(Input, [<<"{{{--">>, <<"--}}}">>], [global])
    ),
    erlang:list_to_binary(List).


get_content(<<"test_placeholder_1">>)->
    <<"test id 1!">>;
get_content(<<"test_placeholder_2">>)->
    <<"test id 2!">>;
get_content(_)->
    <<"not found text!">>.
```

In case you need more powerfull tool for tasks like this

I feel you should check ErlyDTL plugin -- [ErlyDTL Wiki](https://github.com/erlydtl/erlydtl/wiki)